# compile install libexpat for mingw under ubuntu

Tags: mingw32

I'm using mingw under ubuntu to create windows executables. I need to use expat. It's not included in the repo, so I gather that I need to install it from sources. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is expat? What is your Ubuntu version? How mingw was installed?

Comment: expat is a well-known library for parsing XML. The Ubuntu version doesn't actually seem to matter, because the mingw distribution in 18.04, 19.04, 20.04 and 21.04 all seem quite similar. But point taken.

Comment: Mingw is different under different versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was pretty easy:

```bsh
$ ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Please make both question and answer reproducible. Where do you run `./configure` and so on. Which Ubuntu version and packages were used.

Comment: A better title would say "compile and install" `expat`.  The rest is self-explanatory once compilation is part of the question.  This is because mingw has a custom prefix path that is uses (it's a power cross-compilation library for win32 executables available on Linux, BSD, MacOS and others).  Projects requiring it will need to find `expat` using (generally) library search path, pkg-config or cmake, but due to cross-compilation sandboxing, they need to be in the right location.  Furthermore, it instructs the compiler the target architecture (confusingly but properly named `--host`)

Comment: Well, I unpacked lib expat into a directory, did a chdir into that directory, and then did the above. Do you want me to add that?